# android location always returns 0 0

Tags: android

I am a beginner so please assume I know nothing when replying.

I am trying to write a very beginner android app to get the last location on my phone. I'm following an online tutorial and basically copied it word by word (I even tried pasting in the source code to see if that would help) but I cannot get the app to work. All it is supposed to do is put a marker on the last location of the phone, but every time it just loads up the default 0,0 (latlong)location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies once again, I'm guessing it's going to be something silly that I am missing? Maybe a setting on my phone or something (GPS is enable). Please let me know if I need to include anything else...I've put the code below...It's basically just one MainActivity. If you think it's useful that I put a logcat in then I can...

```
package com.example.android.iamhere;

import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are trying via emulator, you will get 0,0. If you are trying on real device, then see if you have given correct permissions, BTW it takes time to get GPS co-ordinates in slow connection

Comment: Why have you put 
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker")); This is causing only one marker of 0,0 to come, remove that line and try again

Comment: Hi penta, you were right, it was actually just taking a long time to get the coordinates, if I wait long enough they do come through. So it does seem to be working now. Thanks again for the advice. It is much appreciated, I am still very new to this so I'm learning slowly.

Comment: Kindly upvote or accept my answer if it has helped you. :-)

Comment: Kindly accept question if it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to type so much, just to get your present location in a google map, Try this code snippet which will give you clear idea on how to get persent location.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
  double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
  static final LatLng PresentLoc = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if (map!=null){
      Marker PresentLoc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PresentLoc).title("Present Position"));

    }

  }
```

Moreover if you want to save the location of the co ordinates, use `SharePreferences` . Just put some time and thinking.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really useful.

Comment: Definitely useful, sorry had to google to figure out how to upvote and accept. I'm new here. Now I will know next time. Thanks again.